# Is need to close prepared statement everytime reassinging it or I can do it once in the end

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

```
    ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    while (rst.next()) {
        Integer languageId = rst.getInt("language_id");
        Map<String, List<UserMessageItem>> listUserMessageItem = new HashMap<String, List<UserMessageItem>>();
        *preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);*// first assignation of preparedStatement
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, languageId);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            //do stuff
            } else {
                //do else stuff

    }

    *preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(DictionaryManager.LOAD_MAX_MESSAGE_ID);*//other assignation of preparedStatement
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    if (resultSet.next()) {
        maxMessageId = resultSet.getInt("MAX(message_id)");
    }

    resultSet.close();
    preparedStatement.close();

    rst.close();
    stmt.close();
```

I have to refactor this stuff... Please don't care about absents of try catch finally block... Any I want to ask u that:should I close preparedStatement before assignation new preparedStatement?

Answer (score 2):

You have to close it each time. Reassigning it creates a new one and releases the old one.

Comment: When it is reassigned means a new one and old objects would have become void isn't it?

Comment: (1) Yes and (2) no. 'The old one becomes void' is meaningless. Objects don't 'become void'. Nothing happens to it at all until GC. That's why you have to close it.

Comment: @EJP Should I close prepared statement two times or if I use preparedStatement.close() it close all instances? (there was this code and it doing fine)

Comment: Close each one before the next reassignment, and the last one at the end. Surely this is obvious? Similarly, you should close each ResultSet. They do all get closed when you close the connection, but you tie up server resources if you leave it until then.

Comment: @EJP thanks, I think this is obvious but I think that code was done like that and who was wright it know some tricks of closing prepared statement))

Comment: There are no 'tricks of closing prepared statements'. You have to close them. Whoever wrote the original code either didn't know that, or was relying on the final close of the connection. It's poor quality code: don't overestimate it. I would use a new PreparedStatement variable for each statement. These days you would use a try-with-resources code structure.